# VBA Conditions inside of Cases

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list of many cases, which define a client ID. In each case there are several If statements that need to be followed in order to return something. As there are only around 15 special cases and the rest are under the "Case Else", in some circumstances a case doesn't follow any of the If statements, thus leaving it blank.

If a certain case doesn't fall under any of the If statements, could I route it to the "Case Else"?

**For example:** In this code, if the ID is 10, however the *Left(ISIN, 2)* is not "US", "UK", or "CH", could  I route the Case to the Case Else?

```
    Case 10

                '(U.S.)
                If klienta_nr = 10 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "US") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                        'min USD 20
                        If Komisija <= 20 Then
                            .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = 20
                            End If
                    End If

                 '(UK)
                If klienta_nr = 10 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "UK") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                        'min GBP 20
                        If Komisija <= 20 Then
                            .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = 20
                            End If
                    End If
                '(Šveices)
                If klienta_nr = 10 And (Left(ISIN, 2) = "CH") Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.002
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                        'min CHF 20
                        If Komisija <= 20 Then
                            .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = 20
                            End If
                    End If


    'Non-special klient cases
    Case Else

              'IP2, 0.03% komisija, 40 EUR/USD Max
                 If Right(vk, 1) = 1 Or Right(vk, 1) = 8 Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.003
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                    End If
              'IP1, 0.1% komisija, 40 EUR/USD Max
                If Right(vk, 1) = 7 Then
                    Komisija = Summa * 0.01
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = Komisija
                    End If
                'Komisija MAX is 40, so anything >=40 equals 40
                If Komisija >= 40 Then
                    .Cells(lngCounter, lngKom) = 40
                    End If
```

Comment: Short answer: No, you can't reroute to a different `Case`. You could however create cases based on some variable that you populate first using the `If ... Then... Else` construction.

Comment: I would recommend looking into `If...ElseIf...Else` since this is close to what you need. I also strongly recommend learning proper indentation since currently your code is difficult to follow due to lack of indentation consistency (e.g Begin `If` indented with one tab, but the corresponding `End If` is indented with two tabs).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although using `Goto` is not recommended to use abusively, but sometimes it makes life easier.

For your situation, you can place a "*label*" before the first statement after the `Case Else` and use `Goto`, i.e.

```
Select Case myExpression

  Case 1
     Some code
     If someThing Then GoTo LabelCaseElse
     Some code

  Case 2
     If someThing Then GoTo LabelCaseElse
     Some code

  Case Else
LabelCaseElse:
    msgBox "You are in Case Else!!"
End Select
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thank you

Comment: Definitely not the most efficient method, but it works. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, didn't have disrespecful intentions. Your answer was helpful and did help me solve my issue. I'm new to VBA and have been trying to create this program from scratch, but issue like this arise.

Comment: @Nikolajs I didn't take it that way, dont worry. always glad to help :)